# How was David's security code still active in Alien-Covenant?

Tags: alien-covenant

**DAVID 73694-B**

I'm guessing the security system could still have his security access code at that point. But why would they (the crew/company/organization) still kept it active?

Do people actually do this in real life? For example, an IT admin at a company leaves for some reason (end of contract/retired/fired) and comes back later. Would he find himself still able to access the whole system with his old assigned credentials?

Is this a flaw in the movie or a plot device?

The discussion at this [link](http://www.alien-covenant.com/topic/45292) suggests David was able to upload himself into Walter.

**Direct quote from link**:

> David Uploaded His Programming into Walter...
>
> You will recall that Daniels stabs David in the chin with the nail
>   pendant that she wears.  Note that the android that is aboard the ship
>   at the end of the movie bears no such scar, indicating that the
>   android chassis is that of Walter.  However, it is clear that David's
>   A.I. now resides in the chassis of Walter once they are back on board
>   the Covenant.
>
> David's programming was either uploaded into Walter, or Walter's
>   programming was "rolled back" to that of David, in a similar way that
>   you can roll back MS Windows to a prior state after a software
>   upgrade.

Comment: HR called IT when he left the company. IT were busy so wrote it on a Post-It note & stuck it to the edge of the monitor. Before they'd had chance to complete the deactivation, the Post-It fell off & is still somewhere under the desk. Blame IT, everybody else does... except IT, who blame HR for not sending the official web form - because IT have not yet been able to schedule their training session for HR. They tried once, but HR were busy so someone wrote it on a Post-It note .... ;)

Comment: Related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73603/how-did-david-know-walters-access-codes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did David use his real name instead of Walter's to get the access to the spaceship?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/91487/why-did-david-use-his-real-name-instead-of-walters-to-get-the-access-to-the-spa)

Answer (score 1):

Mother is installed in all of Wayland Corp ships and David's code was never deactivated. He would have the highest level of clearance being Peters Prodigy creation and able to work on any Wayland ship.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but it looks like the same digits from SPECIAL ORDER 937 was use in his authorisation code, Alien(1979). I think it is essential for all saga to keep this order as priority. That's is why David is an Admin perhaps even more - biohazard engineer or Creator.

SPECIAL ORDER 937
Priority one: Insure return of organism for analysis.
All other considerations secondary.
Crew expendable.

Comment: Didn't the events of *Alien: Covenant* take place before the events of *Alien*?