# Why did David use his real name instead of Walter's to get the access to the spaceship?

Tags: plot-explanation, alien-covenant

In *Alien: Covenant* (2017) we can see two android robots that look the same. The robots' names are David and Walter. David was already on the alien planet when robot Walter (and others) came to the planet.

Towards the end of the movie, why did David use his real name instead of Walter's to get the access to the colonists (spaceship)?

Comment: what do you mean? I don't understand the question

Comment: Is there a reason David should have said he was Walter, instead of using his own name?

Comment: @BrettFromLA In the movie, both robots look the same, however one of them isn't exactly the nicest of fellows and is trying to hide he's the other robot. Hence why should use his other name. They have a fight at one moment and you're not actually sure who won between the two

Answer (score 3):

David is using his personal access code.  As the personal android of the Owner of Weyland Corp ("The Company") he likely had high level access to any ship or system owned by the company.

Also he would likely not know Walter's codes, as he would need to extract them before taking Walter's place.

Comment: That was the big reveal. That the whole thing is business as usual. *"gotcha"*